# How do I respond to a “CONNECT” method request in a proxy server using socket in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am using node to implement proxy function，I want to perform some verification on the client before proxying. The data from the client will only be forwarded after the verification is successful. If the verification fails, then I need to inform the client of the failure reason. How can I send the failure reason to the client?

```
httpTunnel.on('connect', async (req, cltSocket, head) => {
 // Check whether it passed
 if (verify(Ciphertext)) {
    // Verification succeeded
    const serverSocket = net.connect({host, port})
 } else {
    // When the authentication fails, notify the client of the failure information, the information is "password error"
    // How to send the "password error" message to the client?
 }
});
```

I tried cltSocket.end and cltSocket.write,But no matter what data I send, the client cannot receive it

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) library. Refer to
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#setup-a-stand-alone-proxy-server-with-custom-server-logic.

Alternatively, if you are using Express, you can use the [http proxy middleware](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy).